# MySQL find rows that do not contain keywords from a lookup table

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I can reject rows from a query where an item is not in a lookup table if there is an **exact match**:

```
select * from mytable where (item not in (select keyword from lookup_table))
```

But now I need to reject rows if the item **contains** any of the keywords in the lookup table

Pseudo code:

```
select *
from mytable
as long as any part of the item field does not contain any keyword from the lookup table

keywords in lookup table: 'something', 'test', 'something else'

item: 'this is a test' would be rejected since it contains 'test'

item: 'this is something else' would be rejected since it contains 'something'
(it would also have been rejected since it contains 'something else')

item: 'this is OK' would be included in the select since it contains none of the keywords
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you need performance, you should consider breaking the input up into tokens containing one word each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from lookup_table l
    where t.item like concat ('%', l.keyword, '%')
)
```